# Change sender name and email address for specific WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

How to change email sender address and name in WooCommerce for specific email notifications?

For example: 
Change the sender name and email address just for customer processing order email notifications.

But not for all email notifications, just for specific ones.

Comment: The email object is passed to the [`woocommerce_email_from_address`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L531) filter as the second variable. That object will have an `id` property that you can use to conditionally change the from address for specific emails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sender name and email address are set here (at the end of Woocommerce "Emails" setting tab:

[image]

This fields are passed through dedicated filters hook that allow you to change conditionally the values.

Here is an example conditionally restricted to "customer processing email notification":

```
// Change sender name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_name', function( $from_name, $wc_email ){
    if( $wc_email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) 
        $from_name = 'Jack the Ripper';

    return $from_name;
}, 10, 2 );

// Change sender adress
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', function( $from_email, $wc_email ){
    if( $wc_email->id == 'customer_processing_order' )
        $from_email = 'jack.the.ripper@freek.com';

    return $from_email;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

> Some other WC_Email Ids that you can use in your condition:
>   - **`'customer_completed_order'`**
>   - **`'customer_on_hold_order'`**
>   - **`'customer_refunded_order'`**
>   - **`'customer_new_account'`**
>   - **`'new_order'`** *( admin notification )*
>   - **`'cancelled_order'`** *( admin notification )*
>   - **`'failed_order'`** *( admin notification )*

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, but can it be done in OOP ?
when i try it like this:
In the constructor: 
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', [ $this, 'email_sender_addressess' ] );`
then the class function
`public function email_sender_addressess( $from_email, $wc_email) { ... }`. The error appears that says that the second parameter is not passed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nikola Try this instead: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', array( $this, 'email_sender_addressess' ), 10, 2 );` where `10` is the priority and `2` the number of parameters in the function … This normally will solve this issue. same thing for the other hook.

Comment: tnx once again.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for this snippet. I am creating a custom plugin in that I just want to send email through ajax. But my problem is how can I check id for it as I am using my custom functions. Can I set an id as well?

Comment: My god, you save lives! The only question I have is:

If your answer wouldn't exist, where on earth this is written in the docs of woocommerce & would someone be able to find it?

Comment: I apologize for being bold. Is it possible to add two sender addresses? I mean, the email address where customer responses to WooCommerce order notifications are sent? Would this be possible @LoicTheAztec? Thank you

Comment: I have seen your new question. Reply to only allow one email address, this is logical, think about it.