# Add order ID to customer sender name in WooCommerce email notification

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How can I add an order number (order_id) to E-Mail Sender Name as follows: #order_id John Doe

For Example: "My Shop" should be changed to "#1234 John Doe".

I am using *[Change sender name to customer billing full name in WooCommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009469/change-sender-name-to-customer-billing-full-name-in-woocommerce-email-notificati/63009829#63009829)* answer code.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `get_id()` function to retrieve the order number and use `sprintf()` to give your string the desired format, like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_name', 'filter_wc_email_from_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_wc_email_from_name( $from_name, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' && is_a($email->object, 'WC_Order') ) {
        $order     = $email->object;
        $from_name = sprintf( '#%s %s', $order->get_id(), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() );
    }
    return $from_name;
}
```